# How to use Lucene full text search in all of the document's fields?

Tags: lucene, full-text-search

Currently I'm working on Apache Lucene 4.6.

Can Lucene search in all of the document's fields?

OR

I have to create another field which will contain all text?

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can search in all of the fields. You just have to know all the field. e.g. when you have the fields `body` and `header` and `title`, and you want to find the word "hello" you can search for `+body:hello +header:hello +title:hello`